# How do I make an html image responsive?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have an html image. Its my logo and then in the top right corner is a link for social media.
I have got the image in place but when I re-size my screen its not responsive like everything else is.

This is what I have;

```
<div id="headerhj" align="center">
  <table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" max-width="100%">
    <!-- fwtable fwsrc="header html.fw.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="main.jpg" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "2088656467" fwnested="0" -->
    <tr>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="815" height="1" /></td>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="25" height="1" /></td>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="6" height="1" /></td>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="24" height="1" /></td>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="1" height="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><img src="img/htm/main_r1_c1.jpg" alt="" name="main_r1_c1" width="815" height="171" id="main_r1_c1" align="middle" /></td>
      <td><a href="www.facebook.com"><img name="main_r1_c2" src="img/htm/main_r1_c2.jpg" width="25" height="24" id="main_r1_c2" alt="" /></a></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><img name="main_r1_c3" src="img/htm/main_r1_c3.jpg" width="6" height="171" id="main_r1_c3" alt="" /></td>
      <td><a href="www.twitter.com"><img name="main_r1_c4" src="img/htm/main_r1_c4.jpg" width="24" height="24" id="main_r1_c4" alt="" /></a></td>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="1" height="24" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img name="main_r2_c2" src="img/htm/main_r2_c2.jpg" width="25" height="147" id="main_r2_c2" alt="" /></td>
      <td><img name="main_r2_c4" src="img/htm/main_r2_c4.jpg" width="24" height="147" id="main_r2_c4" alt="" /></td>
      <td><img src="img/htm/spacer.gif" alt="" name="undefined_2" width="1" height="147" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</headerhj>
```

Where have I gone wrong please?

Comment: Your example doesn't have an image in it

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: You need to use CSS, not just HTML on `<td>` and/or the `<img>` take a look at `min-width` `max-width` and `width` percentages, rather than just hardcoding in the HTML

Comment: Hey man, it would be useful if you can provide a code snippet in your question, not just code but the actual JS/CSS/HTML palette, it's one of the top icons in the text editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in you'r css file :

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

this will affect all img elements.
to be more specific, you can use a specific id like :

```
#headerhj img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

see : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: It works but there is an issue with height. It leaves a huge gap from the top of web page.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use CSS with a `<style>` tag or inline `<img style="width:100%">` for example

> It looks like you're hardcoding the `<img>` widths and heights, so they won't respond, as they aren't driven by percentages of the containing `<td>`

Normally, in order to use percentages, the parent container has to have a hardcoded value, even if it's a percentage of something else, not sure how this principle would apply to a table

Take a look at `min-width` `max-width` and `width` with percentages and `auto`