# CSS code to get dynamic scaling images with blogger

Tags: css, blogs, blogger

for my portfolio site, I would like to implement some CSS code that would allow me to control the variables for dynamically scaling images on my Blogger. http://www.bryan3d.com

This means that as you manipulate your window via resizing, the scaling of the images (hosted by imgur) would be resized on the fly.

A working example of this functionality can be seen here, though the user is using Squarespace: http://jasonlavoie.net/personal/#/deusudk-environmentart/

Is there something I can implement to have the same functionality through blogger?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer : [How do I make an html image responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685581/how-do-i-make-an-html-image-responsive/34685671#34685671)

Add this in you'r css file :

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

this will affect all img elements. to be more specific, you can use a specific id like :

```
#headerhj img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

see : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp